# Open S3 object as a string with Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I'm aware that with Boto 2 it's possible to open an S3 object as a string with: [`get_contents_as_string()`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/file.html?highlight=contents%20string#boto.file.key.Key.get_contents_as_string)

Is there an equivalent function in boto3 ?

Answer (score 372):

`read` will return bytes. At least for Python 3, if you want to return a string, you have to decode using the right encoding:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: to get this answer to work, I had to `import botocore` as `obj.get()['Body']` is of type `<class 'botocore.response.StreamingBody'>`

Comment: @TzunghsingDavidWong you shouldn't have to import a package to call methods on an existing object, right?  Was that maybe only necessary while experimenting?

Comment: what is the value of key in the obj = s3.Object(bucket,key)  ** bucket is buckername?? and key is the file name???*** please correct me if i m wrong...

Comment: @Amaresh yes, bucket = bucket name and key = filename

Comment: if a key is pdf format , is it work ? or please suggest another useful way, I tried import textract
text = textract.process('path/to/a.pdf', method='pdfminer')
It will sow import error

Comment: @gatsby-lee's answer below is MUCH faster than this. I get 120mb/s vs 24mb/s

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simplest way for simple cases. If you deal with big files, it is obvious you would want some stream support and multi part, but it is advanced usage.

Answer (score 173):

I had a problem to read/parse the object from S3 because of `.get()` using Python 2.7 inside an AWS Lambda.

I added json to the example to show it became parsable :)

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
j = json.loads(obj['Body'].read())
```

NOTE (for python 2.7): My object is all ascii, so I don't need `.decode('utf-8')`

NOTE (for python 3): We moved to python 3 and discovered that `read()` now returns `bytes` so if you want to get a string out of it, you must use:

`j = json.loads(obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Worked for me! AWS Boto3 documentation is a mess

Comment: If you're using the json library you could also convert to string the following way -
`j = json.loads(obj['Body'].read()`
`string_j = json.dumps(j)`

Answer (score 87):

This isn't in the boto3 documentation. This worked for me:

```
object.get()["Body"].read()
```

object being an s3 object: http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object

Comment: assuming "Body" contains string data, ou can use object.get()["Body"].read() to convert to a Python string.

Comment: boto3 get terrible doc, as of 2016.

Comment: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.get tells us the return value is a dict, with a key "Body" of type StreamingBody, searching for that in read the docs gets you to http://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/response.html which will tell you to use read().

Comment: seems that now `get expected at least 1 arguments, got 0`. Remove the `get()` and access the "Body" object property directly

Answer (score 51):

Python3 + Using boto3 API approach.

By using **S3.Client.download_fileobj API** and **Python file-like object**, S3 Object content can be retrieved to memory.

Since the retrieved content is bytes, in order to convert to **str**, it need to be decoded.

```
import io
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
bytes_buffer = io.BytesIO()
client.download_fileobj(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key, Fileobj=bytes_buffer)
byte_value = bytes_buffer.getvalue()
str_value = byte_value.decode() #python3, default decoding is utf-8
```

Comment: This is MUCH faster than `object.get()["Body"].read()` method.

Comment: FYI, if the content size is big, you will have pressure in memory.

Comment: honestly, although I am the writer of this reply, I keep coming back to refer the code again. lol

Comment: This should be the answer. This is faster than any other method (@Jakobovski) because it uses multi-parts download. Basically it spreads the download of different pieces of the file on multiple processes and then merge the result together

Comment: @ciurlaro can you share where I can find out the logic you described?

Comment: @GatsbyLee you can find it mentioned [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_fileobj): *"[...] will perform a multipart download in multiple threads if necessary"*. Notice that you can customise furtherly the parallelisation details (concurrency, batch_size, etc) specifying the `Config` which must be an instance of [the class `TransferConfig`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/s3.html#boto3.s3.transfer.TransferConfig)

Comment: @GatsbyLee I made a separate answer with an example, it was too much code to be written here

Answer (score 5):

## Fastest approach

As stated in the documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_fileobj), `download_fileobj` uses parallelisation:

> This is a managed transfer which will perform a multipart download in multiple threads if necessary.

Quoting [aws documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/parallelizing-large-downloads-for-optimal-speed/):

> You can retrieve a part of an object from S3 by specifying the [part number](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.html#withPartNumber(java.lang.Integer)) in GetObjectRequest. TransferManager uses this logic to download all parts of an object asynchronously and writes them to individual, temporary files. The temporary files are then merged into the destination file provided by the user.

---

This can be exploited keeping the data in memory instead of writing it into a file.

The approach that `@Gatsby Lee` has shown does it and that's the reason why it **is the fastest** among those that are listed.
Anyway, it can be improved even more using the `Config` parameter:

```py
import io
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')
buffer = io.BytesIO()

# This is just an example, parameters should be fine tuned according to:
# 1. The size of the object that is being read (bigger the file, bigger the chunks)
# 2. The number of threads available on the machine that runs this code

config = TransferConfig(
    multipart_threshold=1024 * 25,   # Concurrent read only if object size > 25MB
    max_concurrency=10,              # Up to 10 concurrent readers
    multipart_chunksize=1024 * 25,   # 25MB chunks per reader
    use_threads=True                 # Must be True to enable multiple readers
)

# This method writes the data into the buffer
client.download_fileobj( 
    Bucket=bucket_name, 
    Key=object_key, 
    Fileobj=buffer,
    Config=config
)

str_value = buffer.getvalue().decode()
```

For objects bigger than 1GB, it is already worth it in terms of speed.

Comment: I tried this and got `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

Answer (score 4):

Decoding the whole object body to one string:

```
obj = s3.Object(bucket, key).get()
big_str = obj['Body'].read().decode()
```

Decoding the object body to strings line-by-line:

```
obj = s3.Object(bucket, key).get()
reader = csv.reader(line.decode() for line in obj['Body'].iter_lines())
```

The default encoding in bytes' `decode()` is already `'utf-8'` since Python 3.

When decoding as JSON, no need to convert to string, as [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) accepts bytes too, since Python 3.6:

```
obj = s3.Object(bucket, key).get()
json.loads(obj['Body'].read())
```

Comment: Thank you. It's good to know that the json.loads takes bytes as well as of 3.6

Answer (score 2):

```js
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
S3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_key).["Body"]
```

is of type <class 'botocore.response.StreamingBody'>

When you call

```
s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_key)["Body"],
```

you are accessing the StreamingBody object that represents the content of the S3 object as a stream. This allows you to read the data in chunks and process it incrementally.

```
s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_key).["Body"].read()
```

On the other hand, when you call s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=s3_key)["Body"].read(), you are reading the entire content of the object into memory and returning it as a bytes object. This is not efficient if the object is large, as it can quickly consume a lot of memory.

Answer (score -7):

If body contains a io.StringIO, you have to do like below:

```
object.get()['Body'].getvalue()
```