# Boto3 Object Read Type error: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to read text that is in a .txt file that is uploaded to the Amazon s3 Bucket. But I am getting an error.

```
import boto3
import json

s3= boto3.resource('s3')
bucketList=[]
i=1
for bucket in s3.buckets.all():
           print(str(i)+'.' + bucket.name)
           bucketList.append(bucket)
           i=i+1
BucketSel=int(input('Select from the bucket list using number'))
AccessBucket=bucketList[BucketSel-1]
FileList=[]
for obj in AccessBucket.objects.all():
           print(obj.key)
           FileList.append(obj.key)
FileSel=int(input('Select the File from the List using number'))
AccessFile=FileList[FileSel-1]
obj=s3.Object(AccessBucket, AccessFile)
str=obj.get()['Body'].read()
```

I am getting this following Error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\pyworkspace\BucketSelectFromList.py", line 20, in <module>
    str=obj.get()['Body'].read()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 586, in _make_api_call
    api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 619, in _convert_to_request_dict
    api_params, operation_model, context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 648, in _emit_api_params
    params=api_params, model=operation_model, context=context)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 227, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\botocore\handlers.py", line 217, in validate_bucket_name
    if VALID_BUCKET.search(bucket) is None:
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I understand that the error occurs at the read() but I am not sure what to do rectify this error.

---

## Solved

I used `obj=s3.Object(AccessBucket.name, AccessFile)` instead of `obj=s3.Object(AccessBucket, AccessFile)` and it's working.

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem when bucket name was configured incorrectly.

Comment: I guess you meant to type `incorrectly`, right?

Comment: Same for me. Had this with an incorrect bucket name.

Answer (score 1):

My error was much more stupid:

```
bucket = f"{client}-media",
```

and that comma at the end made `bucket` a non-string.

Answer (score 0):

From the [get() documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.ObjectSummary.get), `.get()` returns a `StreamingBody`. This is a series of **bytes, not a string**.

From [Open S3 object as a string with Boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35376156/174777), you can use:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
obj.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

If that fails, then I would recommend that you **download** the object to your local filesystem and then use standard Python commands to read the file.

Comment: Thanks the problem was that I was passing a bucket object instead of the bucket name into thes3.Object. Now its working

Comment: Consider adding an answer that solves the issue and marks it as the right one. This will facilitate people finding the solution.

Comment: @srivatsansozhavaram Can you add your solution an answer on with code? I have similar problem as well.

Comment: I used obj=s3.Object(AccessBucket.name, AccessFile) instead of obj=s3.Object(AccessBucket, AccessFile) and it's working.