# Should we close botocore's StreamingBody?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore

The `close()` method of `StreamingBody` is [clearly documented](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html). However, it is unclear whether we should proactively close it after use.

As of [the few examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976273/open-s3-object-as-a-string-with-boto3) I have seen, the `close()` method is never explicitly called.

My concern/question is, if we don't explicitly close it, wouldn't there be the risk of leaking connections.