# How to read content of a file from a folder in S3 bucket using python?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I was trying to read a file from a folder structure in S3 bucket using python with boto3.

I want to return boolean value wether the report is present in S3 bucket or not.

#### Code

```
import boto3
import json

S3_BUCKET_NAME = ''
KEY = '@@@/%%%.json'


def notification():
    report = get_report()
    print(report)


def get_report():
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=S3_BUCKET_NAME, Prefix=PREFIX, Key=KEY)
    data = response['Body'].read()
    report = json.loads(data)
    return report
```

How to check if the report is present and return a boolean value ?

Comment: S3 is an Object storage and unlike block storage or file storage the folder and the filename altogether constitute the object location so "Key" should be  "/fee_summary/fee_summary_report.json" and you should drop the parameter "Prefix"

Comment: A `Key` should not start with a `/` slash. The `Key` would be: `fee_summary/fee_summary_report.json`

Answer (score 5):

2 answers to your questions:

1. How to read content of a file from a folder in S3 bucket using python?
2. How to check if the report is present and return a boolean value ?

### Get S3-object

#### S3-object as bytes

```
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=S3_BUCKET_NAME, Prefix=PREFIX, Key=KEY)
    bytes = response['Body'].read()  # returns bytes since Python 3.6+
```

NOTE: For Python 3.6+ `read()` returns **bytes**. So if you want to get a string out of it, you must use `.decode(charset)` on it:

```
pythonObject = json.loads(obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8'))
```

#### S3-object as string

See [Open S3 object as a string with Boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31976273/open-s3-object-as-a-string-with-boto3).

### Check if S3-object is present

For example to check the availability of the report as [`S3.Object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object) just retrieve it and test on the `key` attribute:

```py
import boto3
import json

S3_BUCKET_NAME = ''
KEY = 'fee_summary/fee_summary_report.json'


def send_fee_summary_notification():
    fee_summary_report = get_fee_summary_report()
    print(fee_summary_report)


def get_fee_summary_report():
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=S3_BUCKET_NAME, Prefix=PREFIX, Key=KEY)
    data = response['Body'].read()
    fee_summary_report = json.loads(data)
    return fee_summary_report


def has_fee_summary_report():    
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    obj = s3.Object(S3_BUCKET_NAME, KEY).get()  # define object with KEY (report) and get
    return obj.key != None # returns False if not found
```

#### Use paging to literally scan (for debugging)

You can also iterate over all objects in you bucket via [paging](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/collections.html#controlling-page-size) and test, if the desired report (with specified KEY) exists:

```py
for page in s3.Bucket('boto3').objects.pages():
    for obj in page:
        print(obj.key)  # debug print
        if obj.key == KEY:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

See example below, I have created for you..

[image: S3 Bucket and JSON file]

```
import json
import boto3


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    S3_BUCKET_NAME = ''
    KEY = 'fee_summary_report.json'
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='feesummarybucketmmmm', Key=KEY)
    data = response['Body'].read()
    print(response)
    print(data)
    fee_summary_report = json.loads(data)
    
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': fee_summary_report
    }
```

[image: output]

https://github.com/mmakadiya/public_files/blob/main/read_s3_file.py

Comment: I was confused by what `key` was; this example clearly shows what that is. Also rememeber to call `decode(charset)` as mentioned on the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/71035707/530399 by @hc_dev